# Procedural material not bending correctly around mesh during animation

Tags: materials, uv, bones, keyframes, procedural

I made a simple mesh and added bones, as I was practicing keyframing a bone structure.  I applied a procedural wood material to the mesh, and applied smart UV projection.  After rendering it out, I noticed that when the mesh bends, the material doesn't follow the deformation, choosing instead to remain "upright".  Attaching below my .blend and a link to the rendered clip.

[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

**Material**
[image]

**Rendered Animation**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=psGZs0R25iQ

**.Blend**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fAdkggf7pFVdGza_jHum_jYY_oAy6pgb/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hello, there's no material in your file, just a Principled BSDF with white color

Comment: ähem...so there IS a material right? :D sorry, couldn't resist. :D :D :D

Comment: lol sorry, I uploaded a version of the file before I added the material.  Fixed now, thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Please edit your question to show screenshots of your material nodes instead of requiring someone to download and open your .blend. This will make the question more accessible and relevant to others as well as guarding against the .blend perhaps not being available in future.

Comment: Thanks Rich, good suggestion.  Edited.

Comment: Most probably it's a texture cordinate problem. I'll look into it

Comment: Found the solution. Gonna get a quick render and write the answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that you used object coordinates. Object coordinates always point towards obeject X, Y and Z-axis. To fix this you have to either change it to UV or Generated coordinates which bend with the object.

**SET TO GENERATED:**
[image]

**SET TO UV:**
[image]

Comment: +1, of course... but object coordinates align to the _object's_ axes, with all their transforms, not the world.. :D

Comment: Thanks for clearing it Robin

Comment: Thanks so much!  Can't believe it was such a simple error!  That's what I get for blindly just setting the input into my texture coordinate node!

Comment: Trust me, it has happened to me more times than you can imagine. That's why I always check my texture coordinates when something goes wrong